# GrahpQL Mutation not returning value of FieldResolver

Tags: typescript, mongodb, graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

I'm using TypeGraphQL and Typegoose to have and API for category trees stored by a reference to the parent. One FieldResolver of it is returning an array of ancestors (using graphLookup).

```js
  @FieldResolver(() => [Category])
  async ancestors(@Root() input: GetCategoryInput) {
    return this.categoryService.getAncestors(input);
  }
```

This works as it should when I query for ancestors but when I create or update a category the ancestors array I get returned is always empty.

Here's the complete Resolver

```js
@Resolver(Category)
export class CategoryResolver implements ResolverInterface<Category> {
  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categoryService = new CategoryService();
  }

  @Query(() => Category)
  category(@Arg("input") input: GetCategoryInput) {
    return this.categoryService.getCategory(input);
  }

  @Query(() => [Category])
  categories() {
    return this.categoryService.getCategories();
  }

  @FieldResolver(() => [Category])
  async ancestors(@Root() input: GetCategoryInput) {
    return this.categoryService.getAncestors(input);
  }

  @FieldResolver(() => [Category])
  async descendants(@Root() input: GetCategoryInput) {
    return this.categoryService.getDescendants(input);
  }

  @Mutation(() => Category)
  async create(@Arg("input") input: CreateCategoryInput) {
    return this.categoryService.createCategory(input);
  }

  @Mutation(() => Category)
  async update(
    @Arg("_id", () => ID) _id: string,
    @Arg("input") input: UpdateCategoryInput
  ) {
    return this.categoryService.updateCategory(_id, input);
  }
}
```

Comment: how is this question related to mongodb / typegoose? i dont see anything related to that inside the code

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
{ new: true }
```

in your find example:

```
UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      _id,
      {
        employee: input,
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```